# pseudo periodic functions in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, asymptote

I am currently at a loss on how to graph the following expression f(x) = cos(11x) - cos(12x)

The graph should look like this :

[image]

But when I add the following code :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        clip=false,
        xmin=0,xmax=6.5*pi,
        xlabel= $t$,
        ylabel=$f(t)$,
        ymin=-2.5,ymax=2.5,
        axis lines=middle,
        %axis x line=middle,
        %axis y line=left,
        %     axis x line=middle,
        xtick={},
        %
        xticklabels={,,},
        xtick style={draw=none}
        ]
        %\addplot[domain=0:2*pi,samples=200,red]{sin(deg(x))}
        %node[right,pos=0.9,font=\footnotesize]{$f(x)=\sin x$};
        \addplot[domain=0:6*pi,samples=200,LightSeaGreen]{cos(deg(11*x)) - cos(deg(12*x))}
        node[below right,pos=1,font=\footnotesize]{$f(t)=\cos(11t) - \cos(12t)$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This is what I am getting (with jagged edges), which does not look good.

[image]

Would there be any nice way to fix this? I am also open to other suggestions to replace TikZ if it can be done looking better with another like Asymptote (which I have tried but looks worse, I have to admit that I am only starting with Asymptote I do get nice results usually, but more complicated stuff like this escapes my limited knowledge at this time).

Thanks in advance for any help that you may provide on the matter.

Comment: I think you kind of have the answer in your code already. Try increasing the number of samples.

Comment: yeah, that works perfectly fine, thanks @TorbjørnT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an Asymptote version of the figure.

[image]

```
import graph;
unitsize(6mm,1.5cm);
real f(real t){return cos(11*t)-cos(12*t);}
real h(real t){return -2*sin(.5*t);}
int smooth=500;
real a=0, b=19;
path grf=graph(f,a,b, smooth);
path grh=graph(h,a,b, smooth);

draw(grh,lightblue);
draw(yscale(-1)*grh,lightblue);
draw(grf,magenta);

label("$f(t)=\cos(11t) - \cos(12t)$",(10,2.5),magenta);
label("$h(t)=\pm 2\sin(t/2)$",(6,-2.5),lightblue);
real[] y={-2,-1,1,2};
xaxis("$t$",0,20,Arrow(TeXHead));
yaxis(Label("$y$",align=E),-2.4,2.4,LeftTicks(y),Arrow(TeXHead));

add(bbox(5mm,invisible));
```

**Update:** Since h(t) is periodic, and f(t) is not periodic, we can use `Hermite` (standard cubic spline interpolation) as recommended in the [Asymptote manual](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/doc/graph.html#index-grid-430). Ranges should be `0` and `6*pi`. To be honest, I don't see much difference ^^

```
int smooth=500;
path grf=graph(f,0,6*pi, smooth,Hermite);
path grh=graph(h,0,6*pi, Hermite(periodic));
```

Additional comments: The figure is showing [the beat phenomena](https://pages.mtu.edu/%7Esuits/beats.html) in music, when mixing (superposition, adding) 2 sounds with distinct-but-near frequencies, see e.g. this

[image]

Comment: Sweet thanks for that code, I'll study it to learn Asymptote a bit more  really nice graph btw, I love how it renders

Comment: @Sephya you can copy the code to http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/ and click Run, then download pdf, png as you want. Also you can embbed the code in your LaTeX document (run on destop or overleaf.com) \begin{asy} <code> \end{asy} and put in the preamble \usepackage{asymptote}

Comment: Yeah I embed all my asymptote code in my LaTeX document already, just didn't know about the website to get almost instantaneous result images compiled (I mostly use it as a previewer of my code before compiling it into LaTeX with Terminal on Mac) and the fact that you can use int smooth to get a better looking graph of that type. Thanks again  really appreciated.

Comment: Using `Hermite` *may* allow you to use a smaller value of `int smooth` while still having a smooth graph, which can in some cases make both the Asymptote compilation and the pdf renderer faster.